# Rigify - How do I add rigify controls to a character which already has an armature with weight paints?

Tags: rigging, rigify

Hello I would like some help with Rigify. I have tried re-naming every bone to match Rigify's naming system but it still does not work.

Comment: Easiest way to do this is just create a meta rig and you can use the joints in your existing rig to align the meta rig and delete all vertex groups and all the old bones then generate a new rigged system from the generated Rigify.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I was hoping to keep all the weight painting.